# How to prioritize which excel sheet to append information to

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dictionary, data-transfer

Following code is a snippet of a larger project I am working on:

```
import os
import pandas as pd 
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile

under4 = pd.ExcelFile('Under4Systems.xlsx')
over3 = pd.ExcelFile('Over3SystemsModified.xlsx')
SystemCount= len(over3.sheet_names)

#sets each full sheet within the work books = to a unique dictionary syntax- un4full['s1']
un4full = {}
ov3full = {}

for z in range(1, int(SystemCount)+ 1): 
    un4full["s{0}".format(z)]= pd.read_excel(under4, 'System'+ str(z))
    ov3full["s{0}".format(z)]= pd.read_excel(over3, 'System'+ str(z))


#sets the length of each sheet = to a unique dictionary syntax- u4row['r1']
u4row = {}
o3row = {}
for z in range(1, int(SystemCount)+ 1): 
    u4row["r{0}".format(z)] = int(len(un4full["s"+str(z)]))
    o3row["r{0}".format(z)] = int(len(ov3full["s"+str(z)]))
    lowval = min(u4row.values())

print(lowval)

for a in ov3full['s1'].values:
    if a in ov3full['s1'].values and a in ov3full['s2'].values and a in ov3full['s3'].values:
              print(a)
```

Both files have the same styling within the excel document (Same headers, and sheet count). I want to iterate over each sheet in the Over3SystemsModified file and have it move the content to the other file.

How do I prioritize what sheet goes first by length? So if System 4 (Sheet 4) has the lowest quantity in file 2, have it iterate over the same sheet/system in file 1, transferring the content, and since the user will show up multiple times across the sheets I want to limit each user to only being transferred 3 times to file 2. So if the user shows up 4 times in file 1, only 3 will be transferred to file 2 leaving the 4th in file 1.